# Spring Security 2 and FormBean field permissions

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Let's say I have a handler in a Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String myHandler(Model m, @RequestParam MyEntity entity)
```

However, `MyEntity` has several fields, some of which need different permissions to be able to view or update. Currently I am populating a `FormBean` from the entity object but at that point I don't know what has been set by the request so I can't check field by field. Any ideas on how to handle this correctly? I want to be able to specify a specific Role for each field that is required to view or update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've seen to address this is using the `InitBinder` and `setAllowedFields` functionality, the following forum post discusses this:

http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=10820

Answer (score 1):

If you are using container security and have access to the HttpServletRequest, you can perhaps leverage the use of the 'isUserInRole' method on the HttpServletRequest ( http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29 )

eg:

```
boolean canEditEmail = request.isUserInRole("ROLE_EDIT_EMAIL");
```